Using FAISS in Databricks
Despite installing the correct package I cannot make the following code work to add an index to a Dataset.
Failing to work at the following line:
embeddings_dataset.add_faiss_index(column="embeddings")

gives the following error message
ImportError: You must install Faiss to use FaissIndex. To do so you can run `conda install -c pytorch faiss-cpu` or `conda install -c pytorch faiss-gpu`. A community supported package is also available on pypi: `pip install faiss-cpu` or `pip install faiss-gpu`. Note that pip may not have the latest version of FAISS, and thus, some of the latest features and bug fixes may not be available

I'm installing by trying a variety of the following:
!pip install --upgrade faiss-gpu==1.7.2
!pip install faiss-gpu
!pip install --upgrade faiss-cpu

But none of these give any different results. The code looks like:
import faiss
from datasets import Dataset

 
embeddings_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(comments_df[0:10])
embeddings_dataset.add_faiss_index(column="embeddings")

